# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mssql.dll'

Tags: sql-server

I have installed xammp with PHP version 5.4.4 in Windows XP. I have added all DLL files and also configured in php.ini file. Still i am getting 'Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.'.

Please tell me what can be the issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is a configuration issue. Go through the following checklist:

- Check the value of `extension_dir` in `php.ini`. Try adding a full path to it like `extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext/"`.
- Run `phpinfo()` to see if the correct `php.ini` file is being loaded. If you can't seem to get it to load the right file add the environment variable `PHPRC` and set it to your PHP path (be sure to restart the server/system so that the environment variable comes into effect).
- This may not be your case but check if the `ext` directory has enough permissions for the user context under which PHP will access files.